# Ruby on Rails - image_tag cannot find local image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to display a logo image with `image_tag`, but it always comes up as a broken image.

```
// application.html.erb

<%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
```

I have "logo.png" in both `/assets/images/logo.png` and `/assets/logo.png` and have tried a lot of variations of the URL such as `images/logo.png`, `/images/logo.png`, `assets/images/logo.png`, etc but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Thank you.

**Edit: Addition information**

I'm using `rails ~> 5.0.1` with `bootstrap-sass ~> 3.3.6`.

The file is located at `/project_base/app/assets/images/logo.png`.

Running `rake assets:clobber & rake assets:precompie` doesn't seem to change anything.

There is no generated asset for `logo.png` in `/project_base/public/...`.

I haven't changed anything in the `development.rb` file, but tried adding:

```
config.assets.digest = false 
config.assets.compile = true
```

which still doesn't seem to effect the images.

Comment: Is this on development or in production? Are you using asset precompilation? Does anything pop up in the web inspector console?

Comment: Dev, I don't believe so, and no, just shows the URL but don't see anything.

Comment: Try running manually `rake assets:clobber` and then `rake assets:precompile`. If this works, then you'll know your app is not precompiling your assets correctly.

Comment: I ran both of those and even restarted my server, still no go. Could this be a JS issue?

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot, but do you have a content security policy tag in your rendered html/layout? something like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * ....`

Comment: Really strange... In cases like this I always consider the possibility of something really weird like mentioning `logo.png` but the real file is `logo.jpg`, or other kind of typo in the file name. It happened to me many times and sometimes things like this take a long time to notice.

Comment: I didn't see anything like that <meta> tag. And I checked the file name and file type. Even tried renaming it and changing it in both places to ensure.

Comment: If you view source or inspect the element, what path is actually in the HTML?

Comment: It generates this html: `<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put your image in assets/images/ and you can load it from any view by

```
<%=image_tag("logo.png")%>
```

if rails fails to find your image then it will throw an exception **AssetNotFound**

Answer (score 1):

try
        <%= image_tag 'logo.png' %>

Also, can I see more of your application.html.erb file?

Comment: Same result without brackets, and there isn't anything special in my `application.html.erb`, it's mostly the default stuff with a few nav buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Rails 5.0.2.

What eventually solved it is changing the version in the following line found, in my case, in config/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails it can be found in config/application.rb as well

```
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

I guess the idea is that every time you update your assets you should update the asset version. I'm not sure it's worth it, so I'll probably will be removing the line completely.